# Jointly normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I encountered the following sentence while reading a textbook and could not figure out why.

> If $x$ and $y$ are jointly normal, then $y$ is a linear (affine) function of $x$: $y = a+bx$.

If someone could explain this to me, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal,

$$
\bigl(
\begin{array}{cc}
x \\
y  \\
\end{array}
\bigl)
\sim N(\bigl(
\begin{array}{cc}
\mu_{x} \\
\mu_{y}  \\
\end{array}
\bigl),
\bigl(
\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{x}^2&\sigma_{xy} \\
\sigma_{xy}&\sigma_{y}^2  \\
\end{array}
\bigl) )
$$

then the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditional on $X$ is

$$
Y|X \sim N(\mu_{y} + \frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}} \rho(x-\mu_{x}), (1-\rho^2)\sigma_{y})
$$

where $\rho=\frac{\sigma_{xy}}{\sigma_{x} \sigma{y}}$.  Then the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X=x$ has the form you described,

$$
E(Y|X)=\mu_{y} + \frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}} \rho(x-\mu_{x})=a+bx
$$

where $a=\mu_{y}-\frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}} \rho \mu_{x}$ and $b=\frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}} \rho$.

Comment: I thought that the author meant the random variable $y$ not the conditional expectation $E(Y|X)$ in the expression $y=a+bx$. Could you construct an example where $x$ and $y$ are jointly normal, and $y$ is not equal to $a+bx$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Any* nondegenerate binormal distribution would serve that purpose, Dave. The simplest example would be a pair of independent standard normal variates.

Comment: @caburke There are several typos in your answer. The conditional mean is $\mu_y + \cdots$ and not $\mu_x + \cdots$ and your final value for $a$ is incorrect too, since you used $\mu_x$ instead of $\mu_y$ and simplified the RHS.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks! The errors have been corrected.

Comment: @caburke One more typo. In your first displayed equation, the mean vector should be $(\mu_x,\mu_y)$ (transposed),

Comment: @DilipSarwate Fixed again.  I think that is all of them.